# How to automatically detect a column with an auto-incrementing data type in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, auto-increment

Is it possible to find out if a Firebird table has an auto-increment column?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-increment column"?  Firebird implements that kind of thing with [triggers and SEQUENCES](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/), rather than a magic attribute or data type.

Comment: @pilcrow Since Firebird 3.0, Firebird has identity columns (which are basically implemented with triggers and sequences, the column is identifiable has being an identity column).

Comment: Ah, looks like the FAQ (and I) needed an update, thanks.

Comment: @pilcrow I'm heavily involved in the Firebird project, but I have absolutely no idea who maintains that firebirdfaq.org site (assuming it is even still maintained); it is/was some community effort outside of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird 2.5 and earlier do not have auto-increment columns, and this is usually worked around by using triggers and sequences (a.k.a. generators), as shown on [this page](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/). There is no general way to detect this style of auto-increment column (though in specific cases, you may be able to infer things from naming conventions of triggers and/or sequences).

Firebird 3.0 introduced identity columns ([`GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-tbl-identity)), and Firebird 4.0 extended this by also adding [`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity).

It is possible to detect this type of auto-increment column by way of the `RDB$IDENTITY_TYPE` column of the system table [`RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-relfields), with values:

> `NULL` - not an identity column
> `0` - identity column, `GENERATED ALWAYS`
> `1` - identity column, `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`

For example, to list all columns that are identity columns:

```sql
select 
  RDB$RELATION_NAME, 
  RDB$FIELD_NAME, 
  decode(RDB$IDENTITY_TYPE, 0, 'ALWAYS', 1, 'DEFAULT', 'unknown type') as IDENTITY_TYPE
from RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
where RDB$IDENTITY_TYPE is not null
```

However, keep in mind that even with Firebird 3.0 and higher, it is still possible tables use the legacy way of triggers + sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP function that retrieves the RDB$TRIGGER_BLR (BLOB) column as text, then parses it to get the column name

```
function getAutoIncrementColumns($table)
{
    $auto_increment_columns = array();
    // add your pdo connection here
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT cast(RDB$TRIGGER_BLR as blob character set utf8) AS STRVAL FROM RDB$TRIGGERS WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0 AND RDB$TRIGGER_TYPE=1 AND RDB$RELATION_NAME=\'YOUR_TABLE_HERE\'');

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    if ($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $str) {
            if (preg_match('`blr_field,(?:\s?[0-9]+,\s?[0-9]+),\s?([^\s]+),`', $str, $out)) {
                $auto_increment_columns[] = str_replace(array('\'', ','), '', $out[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $auto_increment_columns;
}
```

Hopefully it may help someone someday